# I cant use from style OutlinedBox Dense - Android

Tags: android, android-styles, material-components-android, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I am using from this `style="@style/Widget.Material3.AutoCompleteTextView.OutlinedBox.Dense"` but get me bellow error:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
```

I added bellow `implementation` but not work yet:

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha13")
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-window-size-class:1.0.0-alpha13")
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:compose-theme-adapter-3:1.0.11'
```

And:

```
...
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
...
```

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="38dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="38dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.Material3.AutoCompleteTextView.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:hint="Email or User Name"
                app:boxStrokeColor="#4E4A4A"
                app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
                app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/Button4">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/eMail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName|textEmailAddress"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.Material3.AutoCompleteTextView.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:hint="Password"
                app:boxStrokeColor="#4E4A4A"
                app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
                app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
                app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/Button4">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/passwords"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/signIn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                android:elevation="15dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Log In"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/Button5" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to use Theme.Material3 in your application

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" //ADD your parent Theme here
    ...

/>
```

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar"> //Change parent theme as per your requirement after Material3
```